# Grafana won't display Solr metrics

Tags: solr, grafana, prometheus

I have installed Grafana and configured it to display data from my Solr servers' metrics. However, no data can be displayed. I keep getting this message from the console:

msg="appending scrape report failed" err="out of bounds

"[Screenshot from the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Q7g.png)

How would I solve this problem and get Grafana to display the metrics from Solr?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My configuration, it works....

into prometheus.yml

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
  static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']
```

Into SOLR_HOME/contrib/prometheus-exporter

```
bin/solr-exporter -p 9090 -b http://Ip-solr:8983/solr -f ./conf/solr-exporter-config.xml
```

Then into prometheus home (same prometheus.yml)

```
./prometheus --log.level=debug --web.listen-address="localhost:9854"
```

Restart grafana service

```
systemctl restart grafana-server
```

Connect to grafana (port 3000 by default)
Create datasource prometheus

```
Name:  Prometheus (default: Yes)
URL: http://yourservername:9854
Access: Server
Save & Test
```

Into Dashboard --> manage import the json file for solr
The template location is `SOLR_HOME/contrib/prometheus-exporter/conf/grafana-solr-dashboard.json`

Note : Use DNS name instead of localhost

Comment: Thanks Quent. I have been busy with work until now and was not able to attend to this problem. I will attempt your solution and inform you. Thanks