# How to integrate Solr as a datasource with Grafana

Tags: solr, cors, firefox-addon, grafana

I am trying to integrate Solr data-source to Grafana as per the documentation mentioned at https://github.com/pueteam/datasource-plugin-solr.

I can see the Solr plugin as an option on the Grafana UI while configuring the datasource. However when I click on the button "Save and Test" the test connection fails thought the datasource is updated. 
the following log is seen in the browser console:

**Browser Log:**

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8983 (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8983 (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)
```

**Update further to the log**

I tried the step as mentioned in [here](https://pointdeveloper.com/how-to-bypass-cors-errors-on-chrome-and-firefox-for-testing) about updating the  `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` parameter to false. But that didn't help either.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: So what URL did you configure?

Comment: @MatsLindh http://localhost:8983

Comment: i didn't provide any other authentication parameters. The url i checked and the solr admin page gets loaded successfully when the url is tried directly from the browser

Comment: Did you configure localhost:8983 or `http://localhost:8983`? Can you look at the network tab in the Chrome devtools and see what the error message is?

Comment: @DanielLee http://localhost:8983. The solr datasource plugin as mentioned in the question has some steps in the readme file. I followed the same. But the test connection fails.

Comment: http is being auto truncated by the editor in stack overflow

Comment: What’s the error message? You will probably have to use the Chrome developer tools to see the real error message from solr. Also check the Grafana server logs for an error.

Comment: Ok. I must mention that I am not using any of the dbs sqlite postgres or mysql. Rather instead using solr as the datasource directly. The log says "database table locked, sleeping then retrying".

Comment: I think you are confusing two things. Grafana per default comes with an SQLite db for saving user data, dashboards etc. That is different from a datasource which returns time series data. That error message about the db table being locked is just an SQLite warning (it just retries and then usually it works) and has nothing to do with the solr datasource. Have you tried looking at the console and network tab in Chrome dev tools yet?

Comment: @DanielLee Sorry about that. i have updated the Qs with the log i rcvd in browser console.

Comment: maybe see my answer into this post, I use Prometheus to monitor Solr with grafana https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699248/grafana-wont-display-solr-metrics/53782135#53782135

Comment: @DanielLee Just included the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin* plugin from chrome store while running it from Chrome and things worked! For FireFox added the Add On CORS Everywhere plugin and it worked again! The problem is mor browser specific. Especially when i am working in offline mode. FireFox plugin xpi file cannot be added as an add on because of error as "Add cannot be installed because the plugin is not trusted and unsigned". It seems if your working offline there are a lot of things difficult to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just included the [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/related?hl=en) plugin from chrome store while running it from Chrome and things worked! For FireFox added the AddOn [CORS Everywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/) plugin and it worked again!

The problem seems to be more browser specific. Especially when working in offline mode. FireFox plugin as .xpi file cannot be added as an add on because of error from firefox browser `"Add cannot be installed because the plugin is not trusted and unsigned"`.

*P.S. Firefox wrongly (or for business purpose) assumes that people would install the plugin at the browser from where they are looking for it. This is not the case in many cases. I may need a plugin to download and install on a browser running on my offline dekstop.*

Comment: This is only a short-term fix. CORS is a security feature in the browser and these plugins are a way to get around the security for testing. I would recommend configuring SOLR correctly - just google for SOLR and CORS and you will find tons of resources (like https://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2015/03/26/going-cross-origin-with-solr/ ). There are posts on Stackoverflow too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579367/post-document-to-solr-4-from-angularjs/22697371#22697371